# Parallel Version Control of Similar Files with GIT

Tags: git, version-control

OK, this is a strange version control question.

There is a file (lets call in A.txt) which is currently being version controlled in git with a "Private Managed Team" approach with about 5 engineers contributing to its development and 1 engineer managing the blessed repo.  The file is basically a list of variables which we use to program our products.

I want to work on a new version of the file for a different product which will have about 15 variable differences from the file I am branching off of.  However, A.txt will continue to be developed by the team, and I would like a simple way to keep these files consistent EXCEPT for the 15 or so changes that I am managing.

Is there a nice way to organize this kind of development with git?  I was thinking of creating a new branch to work on my changes and just merging the master into the branch once in a while, but my development won't necessarily be in the same repo.

Comment: When you say it won't be in the same repo, do you mean an entirely different project, or just not literally the same repo, i.e. a clone of the one the other devs are working on?

Comment: I mean an entirely different project.

Answer (score 0):

If it is in a different repo (as in a clone of the original repo), that means you would like to pull just one file from the original repo in order to merge evolutions into `A.txt`.

You can:

- add a remote referring the original repo
- fetch from it
- `git checkout -m revision  -- A.txt`

That will merge A.txt from 'revision' (like `original/master`) to your current `A.txt` of your local repo.